# White page after setting up reverse proxy for geoserver: Why?

Tags: geoserver, proxy

I have installed Geoserver 2.5 in Tomcat6 on a Windows server 2008 R2. I want to have internet access to geoserver so I asked my IT Dept to set up a reverse proxy to internal address using their proxy server in the DMZ. When requesting the geoserver URL I just get a blank page with no source code.

https://egov3.heidekreis.de/geoserver

Can anyone suggest why this is not working?

Comment: Its almost impossible to tell without some more information. Misconfigured geoserver, misconfigured DMZ proxy, firewall issues... Can you provide some more details on what debugging you've done? What is in the geoserver and tomcat logs?

Comment: This question is not really a GIS question. You should work with a web developer/sysadmin to unravel the issue here. I've achieved reverse proxy success using IIS and Nginx, but it involves a bit of trial an error for me. Maybe read the docs: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis

Answer (score 1):

I manage to solve this by creating a URL rewrite rule in IIS. I now have internet access, but somethings are not working...e.g. Geowebcache is now giving me 404: cannot communicate with the server and after a while, the domainname switches to the IP address.

Comment: did you found the complete solution on how to setup the reverse proxy on iis to geoserver ? do you like to share .